How to prove the inequality $S = \frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+...+\frac{1}{2024^3} < \frac{5}{24} $
As in the title
$S = \frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+...+\frac{1}{2024^3} < \frac{5}{24} $
I plan to calculate the sum $$S = \frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^3},$$ but it seems that's not easy after searching in Stack Exchange for some related questions.
I think there might be another easier approach to this question such as
$$n^3>n^3-n \rightarrow \frac{1}{n^3}<\frac{1}{(n-1)n(n+1)}
=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{(n-1)n}- \frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right].$$
when I apply this, I got:
$$S = \frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+...+\frac{1}{2024^3} < \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{2024.2025}\right]$$
But, $$ \frac{5}{24} < \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{2024.2025}\right].$$
So the inequality to prove is tighter than the intermediate one I plan to use.
Any idea to get a closer intermediate inequality to prove $S<\frac{5}{24}$

From which contest is this problem?

A homework my son ask me to help him as he's stuck for couple of days.

Have you tried the factorization of the $\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n-1)}$?

@openspace, yes. That's what is shown in my original question.

Knowing this constant gives a very simple solution.

Use your inequality：
$$n^3>n^3-n \implies \frac{1}{n^3}<\frac{1}{(n-1)n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{(n-1)n}- \frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right],\quad \forall n>2.$$
So (improve you method by keeping the first term)
$$S = \frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2024^3}
 <\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{2\times 3}-\frac{1}{2024\times2025}\right]\\
=\frac5{24}-\frac{1}{4048\times2025}
<\frac5{24}.$$
And this would kill your inequality right away.

Note that $\frac{1}{x^3}$ is a decreasing function and therefore
$$
\frac{1}{n^3} \le \int_{n-1}^n \frac{dx}{x^3} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)^2} - \frac{1}{n^2}\right)
$$
So $\left(\sum_{k=a+1}^b \frac{1}{k^3}\right) \le \frac{1}{2a^2} - \frac{1}{2b^2} < \frac{1}{2a^2}$.
$$
\frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \frac{1}{4^3} + \frac{1}{5^3} +\cdots + \frac{1}{2024^3} < \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \frac{1}{4^3} + \frac{1}{5^3} + \frac{1}{2\cdot 5^2} < \frac 5{24}
$$
Update: with your approximation it suffices to note that
$$
\frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2024^3} < \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{2\cdot (3-1)\cdot 3} = \frac{5}{24}
$$

The integral estimate seems to be a bit less precise than the one you used, and the same idea of estimating only the "tail" of the sum could be applied to your method, possibly allowing for less terms to be used

Just for your curiosity.
If you are familiar with generalized harmonic numbers
$$S_n=\sum_{i=2}^n \frac 1 {i^3}=H_n^{(3)}-1$$ Using their asymptotics
$$S_n=(\zeta (3)-1)-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+\frac{1}{2n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ which gives tight upper and lower bounds.
$\zeta (3)$ is Apéry's constant $(1.20206\cdots)$

I would like to recall a series representation (convergence acceleration) of Apéry's constant $\zeta(3)$ that was historically crucial in Apéry's theorem that states that Apéry's constant is irrational, i.e. $\zeta(3)\notin\mathbb Q$.
$$\zeta(3)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^3}= \frac{5}{2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}k!^2}{(2k)! k^3}\tag{1}$$
The series results from a creative telescoping or Euler's acceleration method. The series converges fast, and with alternating signs, a sufficient upper bound can be obtained with just $3$ terms. So,
$$\zeta(3)<\frac{5}{2} \sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{(-1)^{k-1}k!^2}{(2k)! k^3}=\frac{1039}{864}=1+\frac{175}{864}=1+\frac{4+\frac{31}{36}}{24}<1+\frac{5}{24}$$
Hence,
$$S = \frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+...+\frac{1}{2024^3}<\zeta(3)-1<\frac{5}{24}\qquad\text{proved.}$$
I hope you find it interesting.

For all $p > 1$ and $n, N \in \mathbb {N}$,
$$\sum_{k = n}^{N} \frac {1}{{k}^{p}} < \sum_{k = n}^{\infty} \frac {1}{{k}^{p}} < \int_{n - 1 / 2}^{\infty} \frac {1}{{x}^{p}} \text {d} x = \int_{0}^{2 / (2 n - 1)} {x}^{p - 2} \text {d} x = \frac {1}{p - 1} \cdot {\Big( \frac {2}{2 n - 1} \Big)}^{p - 1}.$$
This is because the function $\mathcal {f}_{p} \left( x \right) = 1 / {x}^{p}$ is decreasing and convex. In your case,
$$\sum_{k = 2}^{2024} \frac {1}{{k}^{3}} < \frac {1}{{2}^{3}} + \frac {1}{3 - 1} \cdot {\Big( \frac {2}{2 \cdot 3 - 1} \Big)}^{3 - 1} = \frac {1}{8} + \frac {1}{2} \cdot \frac {4}{25} = \frac {41}{200},$$
and
$$\frac {41}{200} - \frac {5}{24} = - \frac {1}{300} < 0.$$
$\blacksquare$
